# Condition for clicking on canvas shapes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, conditional-statements

I don't why in else section my condition is false this is my code address:
I don't know this condition isn't work correctly(line 49 in js section)?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/testtest/5pq23me2/5/)

```
<div id="ways" style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;height:100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `turnclicking` variable becomes 3+, this part:

```
while (circle = circles[i++]) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            if (context.isPointInPath(x, y) && (circle.clicked && (cnt == 0))) {
                cnt++;
                console.log("Cnt1: " + cnt);
                break;
            } else {
                alert("You can't go there!  " + (circle.clicked && (cnt == 0)) + "   " + context.isPointInPath(x, y) + "  " + x + "   " + y);
                break;
            }
        }
```

will only check for the 1st circle - because as you see both `if` and `else` functions will cause a break.

That's why your code works fine only for the first 3 clicks, after that the only circle it doesn't fail for is the first one (no idea what's the purpose of the app though).

To fix it, it's probably the best to iterate over all 6 circles, see if one of them was clicked, and **only after that** show the error alert in case no circles were clicked.

---

Here's the version that checks all clicked circles first, and throws the alert if none of them are clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/5pq23me2/6/

Comment: I want just know why condition in line 49 not work correctly? and you pasted this code is for another section of codes!

Comment: Line 4 of what I pasted is the line 49 you're talking about, so I pasted the right thing. The condition works for the first circle, your while loop exits after checking the first one, as I said.

Comment: You're welcome, I gave you a working example in my answer update.